# Solve different equation with eigenvalues (multiplicity > 1) and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve

$$
\frac{du}{dt} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix} u
$$

For $A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$, there is only one eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$, and the corresponding eigenvector is $x=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$

so, shouldn't the solution be
$$u = c e^t\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$$.

But from the ref solution, I see

$$u = c_1 e^t\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 
t
\end{bmatrix} + c_2 e^t\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$$

I wonder how is the $\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 
t
\end{bmatrix}$ part derived?

Comment: The solution set is two dimensional, so your suggestion is not enough.

Comment: Your question is more or less answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289122/general-solution-to-u-left-beginsmallmatrix-1-1-0-1-endsmallmatr?rq=1)

Comment: @Moo, how to get to the third equation the, esp. the $\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 
t
\end{bmatrix}$ part?

Answer (score 1):

This may be formulated as $\frac{du}{dt}=Au$, where
$$
              A =\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{matrix}\right].
$$
And $A=I+N$ where $N^2=0$. The solution is
$$
             u(t)=e^{tA}u(0)=e^{tI}e^{tN}u(0)=e^{tI}(I+tN)u(0)=e^{t}u(0)+te^{t}Nu(0).
$$